# VBA Code to Get data from local HTML file

Tags: excel, vba

I am very basic in VBA for excel and working on a job like copy data from a HTML file which is containing repeated structure (a module) as image. Each module, I want to get the data then copy it to each excel row. Please see the image for better understanding my intention.
[click for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OXUC.jpg)
Any idea of coding or codes would be highly appreciated.

Thank you.
Hung Lam

Comment: Welcome to SO. What you are trying to do is fairly easy and there's a ton of examples in here. You will need to work with the `Microsoft HTML Object Library` and use the `HTMLDocument` and `HTMLAnchorElement` objects as well as methods like `.getElementsByTagName()`. That's a good starting point for you to start researching.

Comment: is it more simple if I change HTML to text file ( .txt extension) ? with that, is it easier to read text file line by line or read in particular line number ?

Comment: No. HTML is easier. Try researching the stuff I mentioned in the comment above. When and if you come up with a more specific question, you can post a new question showcasing your efforts and asking for targeted help. Keep in mind that SO is not a free coding service. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import multiple images into separate rows in Excel you can use the either of the techniques below.

Technique #1:

```
Sub InsertPics()
Dim fPath As String, fName As String
Dim r As Range, rng As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
fPath = "C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\"
Set rng = Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
i = 1

For Each r In rng
    fName = Dir(fPath)
    Do While fName <> ""
        If fName = r.Value Then
            With ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(fPath & fName)
                .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
                Set px = .ShapeRange
                If .ShapeRange.Width > Rows(i).Columns(2).Width Then .ShapeRange.Width = Columns(2).Width
                    With Cells(i, 2)
                        px.Top = .Top
                        px.Left = .Left
                        .RowHeight = px.Height
                    End With
            End With
        End If
        fName = Dir
    Loop
    i = i + 1
Next r
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

' Note: you need the file extension, such as ',jpg', or whatever you are using, so you can match on that.
```

Technique #2:

```
Sub Insert()

    Dim strFolder As String
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim objPic As Picture
    Dim rngCell As Range

    strFolder = "C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\" 'change the path accordingly
    If Right(strFolder, 1) <> "\" Then
        strFolder = strFolder & "\"
    End If

    Set rngCell = Range("E1") 'starting cell

    strFileName = Dir(strFolder & "*.jpg", vbNormal) 'filter for .png files

    Do While Len(strFileName) > 0
        Set objPic = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(strFolder & strFileName)
        With objPic
            .Left = rngCell.Left
            .Top = rngCell.Top
            .Height = rngCell.RowHeight
            .Placement = xlMoveAndSize
        End With
        Set rngCell = rngCell.Offset(1, 0)
        strFileName = Dir
    Loop

End Sub
```